# How to add CSS on SVG file in io.js ?

Tags: node.js, svg, d3.js, jsdom

I'm using io.js, jsdom and D3.

I'm trying to add css to an SVG file generated with D3 as in this example
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

CSS added it this way https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style

but doesnt work , I'm doing wrong?, any ideas? 
this is my script 
https://gist.github.com/ripper2hl/4b0d25c90761ed7840f6

Comment: The problem in my code was basic, just missing add the style attribute(`type='text/css'`) in the tag style xD.
Check the revision 2 from my gist

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine and prints the style too, maybe the `d3` you require does something weird? What's your output? What's the problem with it?

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env(
  "",
  [ 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' ],
  function (err, window) {
    var d3 = window.d3;
    var document = window.document;
    var margin = {
        top : 40,
        right : 40,
        bottom : 40,
        left : 40
    };
    var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select(document.body)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("version", 1.1)
      .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
      .attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height",height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var style='\n /* <![CDATA[ */\n.bar {\n  fill: steelblue;\n}\n\n.bar:hover {\n  fill: brown;\n}\n\n.title {\n  font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n}\n\n.axis {\n  font: 10px sans-serif;\n}\n\n.axis path,\n.axis line {\n  fill: none;\n  stroke: #000;\n  shape-rendering: crispEdges;\n}\n\n.x.axis path {\n  display: none;\n}\n /* ]]> */\n';
    d3.select(document.head).append("style")
      .text(style);

    console.log(window.d3.select(window.document.body).html());
  }
);
```

Comment: The code works fine, but is not interpreted css,check this https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B85reAknFbeXVzVveTBWR1hjRWs&authuser=0

Comment: @JesusPerales You'll have to add the style tag to the head of our document instead of the body. Edited the code to reflect that.

Comment: It worked by adding the type = "text / css" attribute, but I would like to see your example